# Get a seq() in R with alternating steps

Tags: r, seq

The `seq` function in R would give me a sequence from `x` to `y` with a *constant* step `m`:

```
seq(x, y, m)
```

E.g. `seq(1,9,2) = c(1,3,5,7,9)`.

What would be the most elegant way to get a sequence from `x` to `y` with *alternating* steps `m1` and `m2`, such that something like `"seq(x, y, c(m1, m2))"` would give me `c(x, x + m1, (x + m1) + m2, (x + m1 + m2) + m1, ..., y)`, each time adding one of the steps (not necessarily reaching up to `y`, of course, as in `seq`)?

Example: `x = 1; y = 19; m1 = 2; m2 = 4` and I get `c(1,3,7,9,13,15,19)`.

Comment: In the Example, where is the cutting point where 2 changes to 4 to make it more dynamic

Comment: @akrun what do you mean by cutting point? The result is `c(1, 1+2, 3+4, 7+2, 9+4, 13+2, 15+4)`. Alternating the step between 2 and 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I arrived the solution by:
1. Use `cumsum` with a vector `c(from,rep(by,times),...)`, with `by` repeated `times = ceiling((to-from)/sum(by))` times.
2. Truncate the sequence by `!(seq > to)`.

```
 seq_alt <- function(from, to, by) {
   seq <- cumsum(c(from,rep(by,ceiling((to-from)/sum(by)))))
   return(seq[! seq > to])
 }
```

Comment: I suggest to repeat only `times = ceiling((to-from)/sum(by))` otherwise your temporary sequency may grow unncessarily large (e.g. `by = c(0.0001,1))`

Answer (score 3):

First `n` terms of this sequence you can generate with

```
x = 1; m1 = 2; m2 = 4

n <- 0:10 # first 11 terms
x + ceiling(n/2)*m1 + ceiling((n-1)/2)*m2
# [1] 1  3  7  9 13 15 19 21 25 27 31
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea,

```
fun1 <- function(x, y, j, z){
if(j >= y) {return(x)}else{
  s1 <- seq(x, y, j+z)
  s2 <- seq(x+j, y, j+z)
  return(sort(c(s1, s2)))
  }
}

fun1(1, 19, 2, 4)
#[1]  1  3  7  9 13 15 19

fun1(1, 40, 4, 3)
#[1]  1  5  8 12 15 19 22 26 29 33 36 40

fun1(3, 56, 7, 10)
#[1]  3 10 20 27 37 44 54

fun1(1, 2, 2, 4)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: `fun1(1,2,2,4)` chucks a slightly cryptic error, and this doesn't generalise very well for more m.

Comment: `seq(1,2,4)` returns `1`. OP might need something like `seq` as he mentioned in the question.

Comment: ok @raymkchow edited to account for that as well, though I doubt it will ever be the case for the OP

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative that uses `diffinv` This method over allocates the values, so as a stopping rule, I get the elements that are less than or equal to the stopping value.

```
seqAlt <- function(start, stop, by1, by2) {
   out <- diffinv(rep(c(by1, by2), ceiling(stop / (by1 + by2))), xi=start)
   return(out[out <= stop])
}

seqAlt(1, 19, 2, 4)
[1]  1  3  7  9 13 15 19
```

Answer (score 2):

perfect example of recycling vectors in R

```
# 1. 
x = 1; y = 19; m1 = 2; m2 = 4
(x:y)[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, m1-1), TRUE, rep(FALSE,m2-1))]
# [1]  1  3  7  9 13 15 19
# 2.
x = 3; y = 56; m1 = 7; m2 = 10
(x:y)[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, m1-1), TRUE, rep(FALSE,m2-1))]
# [1]  3 10 20 27 37 44 54
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Reduce` with `accumulate = TRUE` to iteratively add either 2 or 4:

```
Reduce(`+`, rep(c(2,4), 10), init = 1, accumulate = TRUE)
# [1]  1  3  7  9 13 15 19 21 25 27 31 33 37 39 43 45 49 51 55 57 61
```

The number of times you repeat `c(2,4)` will determine sequence length; since it is 10 above, the sequence is length 20.

The `purrr` package has an `accumulate` wrapper, if you prefer the syntax:

```
purrr::accumulate(rep(c(2,4), 10), `+`, .init = 1)
## [1]  1  3  7  9 13 15 19 21 25 27 31 33 37 39 43 45 49 51 55 57 61
```