# R, how to create a sequence of numbers with gaps in it?

Tags: r, seq

How to efficiently generate the following sequence of numbers in R?
4, 5, 10, 11, 16, 17, ..., 178, 179

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/q/41843388/496803 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41586530/get-a-seq-in-r-with-alternating-steps

Comment: Marking as duplicate as `(4:179)[rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), c(2,4))]` per the linked question is also a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to think of it as the union of two sequences.

```
sort(c(seq(4,178,6), seq(5,179,6)))
 [1]   4   5  10  11  16  17  22  23  28  29  34  35  40  41  46  47  52  53  58
[20]  59  64  65  70  71  76  77  82  83  88  89  94  95 100 101 106 107 112 113
[39] 118 119 124 125 130 131 136 137 142 143 148 149 154 155 160 161 166 167 172
[58] 173 178 179
```